# getting error of can not implicit convert type generic list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have a class.

```
 public partial class RecentlyViewedReport
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual Report Report { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method where I am retrieving the data from sql table.

```
        public List<RecentlyViewedReport> GetRecentlyViewedReports(string userEmailId)
    {
        var result = (from pd in _context.RecentlyViewedReports
                 join od in _context.Reports on pd.ReportId equals od.Id
                 orderby pd.DateTime descending
                 select 
                 new
                 {
                     Id= pd.Id,
                     Email= pd.Email,
                     ReportId=pd.ReportId,
                     DateTime=pd.DateTime,
                     Report= od as Report //This lines giving me error
                 }).ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

what is the correct way to retrieve the data of Report

Comment: od is a List. If you are expecting exactly one Report, then could you try "od.First() as Report"

Comment: I got the solutions.

Comment: select new RecentlyViewedReport()
                          {
                              Id = pd.Id,
                              Email = pd.Email,
                              ReportId = pd.ReportId,
                              DateTime = pd.DateTime,
                              Report = od
                          }).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 var result = _context.RecentlyViewedReports.Include(c => c.Report)
                       .OrderByDescending(c => c.DateTime)
                       .Select(c => new
                         {
                           Id = c.Id,
                           Email = c.Email,
                           ReportId = c.ReportId,
                           DateTime = c.DateTime,
                           Report = c.Report
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: future readers would really profit from an explanation as to why your code solves the problem and what OP did wrong in the first place with their approach.